# Difference of code result using step by step with the vs debugger and running normally Python

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

Hello I try to get some data from a web page with selenium. But some weird things happen that I doesn't understand. When I run my programm step by step with the debugger it works but running normaly it doesn't. I haven't seen any post related on python or selenium on the internet.
Here is my code :

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


if __name__ == '__main__':
    L=[]
    PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

    options=uc.ChromeOptions()
    pref={"download.default_directory" : r"C:\Users\Dimitri\Documents\Programme C++\clis\extraction+sql\ressources"}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",pref)
    options.headless=True
    driver=uc.Chrome(excutable_path=PATH,options=options)
    driver.get("https://framagenda.org/login?redirect_url=/apps/calendar/dayGridMonth/now")
    user = driver.find_element("id","user")
    user.send_keys("user@gmail.com")
    mdp=driver.find_element("id","password")
    mdp.send_keys("test123")
    mdp.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    print(driver.title)
    
    
    
    list=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"app-navigation-entry__title")
    for l in list:
        L.append(l.text)


    print(L)


    for l in L:
        driver.get("https://framagenda.org/remote.php/dav/calendars/Dimitri%20L./"+l.lower()+"/?export")
```

Note that i doesn't understand the first if of the problem i put it here for fixing an error that i've seen on this forum

When the code is running normally the line :" list=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"app-navigation-entry__title")" seems not to be executed
Have you any idea of what's going wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please, describe "it works." What is the difference between what you expect and what you observe?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Step by step my list L is filled by strings as i want , normally it remains empty

Comment: And what is meant by "step by step?" Are you using a debugger to step through the code or running lines step by step in an interactive session?

Comment: It's with the debugger of visual studio more specially it work only if i had a break point on the line : list=driver.find_elements....

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail so that we can reproduce your problem and help you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses and sorry for not being clear enough. I finally succeeded to address my issue. The problem was that when i ran my code normally the webpage wasn't loading fast enough as a consequence my program was not able to get the element it needed because the webpage was not loaded though when i uses step by step the webpage had enough time to load.
I fixed the issue using time.sleep(2) before getting the data that I want